# How to take care of Vec input when I want to build Functional Module Creation

Tags: scala, chisel

I have a Module which input type is Vec(10,UInt(1.W)), now I want to build Functional Module Creation for it. I follow the chisel wiki, and write this one:

```
object mul{
    def apply (din_1: Vec, din_2: Vec) = {
        val m = Module(new mul)
        m.io.din_1 := din_1
        m.io.din_2 := din_2
        m.io.dout
    }
}
```

but get sbt error like this:

```
[error] /home/zqc/rs/decoder/mul_dual.scala:67:27: type Vec takes type parameters
```

Anyone knows how to settle this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer in OneHot.scala, just use `Vec[UInt]`